# How to use multi logger in Python

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I try to use two different loggers to handle different log levels. For example, I want info message store in a file and don't log error message. Error messages of some special functions will email to the user.

I write a simple program to test the logging module.

Code:

```
import logging

def_logger = logging.getLogger("debuglogger")
def_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

maillogger = logging.getLogger("mail")
maillogger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
mailhandler = logging.StreamHandler()
mailhandler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
mailhandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('Error:  %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
maillogger.addHandler(mailhandler)


print(def_logger.getEffectiveLevel())
print(maillogger.getEffectiveLevel())
def_logger.info("info 1")
maillogger.info("info 2")
def_logger.error("error 1")
maillogger.error("error 2")
```

Output:
[Output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03p4B.png)

I can see the level of them is correct, but both of them act like the level is ERROR.

How can I correctly configure them?

Answer: Base on blues advice, I added a handler and it solved my problem.
Here is the modified code:

```
import logging

def_logger = logging.getLogger("debuglogger")
def_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
def_logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler()) #added a handler here

maillogger = logging.getLogger("mail")
maillogger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
mailhandler = logging.StreamHandler()
mailhandler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
mailhandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('Error:  %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
maillogger.addHandler(mailhandler)


print(def_logger.getEffectiveLevel())
print(maillogger.getEffectiveLevel())
def_logger.info("info 1")
maillogger.info("info 2")
def_logger.error("error 1")
maillogger.error("error 2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the def_logger nor any of its parents have a handler attached to it. So what happens is that the logging module falls back to `logging.lastResort` which by default is a StreamHandler with level Warning. That is the reason why the info message doesn't appear, while the error does. So to solve your problem attach a handler to the def_logger.

Note: In your scenario the only parent both loggers have is the default root handler.

Comment: This is clear to me. Seems like I misunderstand the concept of handler and logger.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `filter` for each logger or handler to process only records of interest

```
import logging


def filter_info(record):
    return True if record.levelno == logging.INFO else False


def filter_error(record):
    return True if record.levelno >= logging.ERROR else False


# define debug logger
def_logger = logging.getLogger("debuglogger")
def_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
def_logger.addFilter(filter_info)               # add filter directly to this logger since you didn't define any handler 

# define handler for mail logger
mail_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
mail_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('Error:  %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
mail_handler.addFilter(filter_error)            # add filter to handler 

mail_logger = logging.getLogger("mail")
mail_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
mail_logger.addHandler(mail_handler)

# test
def_logger.info("info 1")
mail_logger.info("info 2")
def_logger.error("error 1")
mail_logger.error("error 2")
```

If `filter` return `True`, the log record is processed. Otherwise, it is skipped.

**Note:**

- Filter attached to a `logger` won't be called for log record that is generated by descendant loggers. For example, if you add a filter to logger `A`, it won't be called for records that are generated by logger `A.B` nor `A.B.C`.
- Filter attached to a `handler` is consulted before an event is emitted by that handler.

This means that you just need one `logger` and add two `handler`s with different filters attached.

```
import logging


def filter_info(record):
    return True if record.levelno == logging.INFO else False


def filter_error(record):
    return True if record.levelno >= logging.ERROR else False


# define your logger
logger = logging.getLogger("myapp")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# define handler for file
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('path_to_log.txt')
file_handler.level = logging.INFO
file_handler.addFilter(filter_info)      # add filter to handler

# define handler for mail
mail_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
mail_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('Error:  %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
mail_handler.addFilter(filter_error)     # add filter to handler

logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(mail_handler)

# test
logger.info("info 1")
logger.info("info 2")
logger.error("error 1")
logger.error("error 2")
```